# File takes too long to get created in windows 7 machine using ruby

Tags: ruby

I am using calabash-android in windows 7 for automation of Android apps.

On ruby prompt when I give command

irb(main):001:0> f = File.new('myoutput.txt','w+')

It takes 20 seconds to create file. is there any way I can speed this.
I am using ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32] and calabash-android 0.5.5

```
It is successfully gets created and give message
irb(main):001:0> f = File.new('myoutput.txt','w+')
#<File:myoutput.txt>
-rw-r--r-- 1 abhijit.shelar Administrators 0 Aug 31 15:05 myoutput.txt
```

but its to slow.

Is File Creation is slower in ruby?

Comment: I want to note that ruby support on windows is very shaky, so you may run into issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an inherent problem in ruby. You could try timing this with something like the following:

`irb(main):001:0> t1 = Time.now; f=File.new('myoutput.txt','w+'); t2 = Time.now; puts t2-t1
0.001
=> nil`

Printed is the number of seconds taken to execute - i.e. around a millisecond - this was run on my win7 box. I'm running a slightly different version than you
(`ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]`) but don't think that's the issue here.

See what you get from the above to see if the timing is as you think.  If it really is, then can you verify the results on a different machine?